# Regex validation YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I am using the [Regex](https://rubular.com/r/q2zsY2iwpktloT) to validate the date format(YYYY-MM-DD) using this gem(https://github.com/nicolasblanco/rails_param)

```
param! :start_date, Date, format: /([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/, required: true, message: "Query start_date is not specified and invalid"
```

For right date format also it is saying error
Query start_date is not specified

A sample query
http://localhost:3005/data?start_date=2008-01-27&end_date=2009-01-27

It's not working

Comment: Also note that this validation, even if it has the correct year syntax, will not make sure the date is correct. You can still receive `2019-02-31` which is not a date that exists but will be valid according to the regex. It's extremely complex to make a correct date validation using regex alone, you're better off just checking for broad conformance and then using a date library for the actual verification.

Comment: @Stefan yeah, I just noticed the `\d` there. I've removed the comment a second before you posted.

Comment: Can we see the full context of the `param!` call? Is it, perhaps, nested?

Comment: Why do you want to validate the string format of a date? Why not just parse it (you do it anyway) and if the parser doesn't raise an error then accept it as correct and if the parser raises an error then you return a useful error message?

Comment: Rubular (https://rubular.com) is a good tool to easily battle-test your regexes

Comment: The string represents a valid date if and only if `DateTime.strptime(input, '%Y-%m-%d')` does not raise an exception. You therefore need to execute that (after `'require 'date'`) within a `begin-rescue-end` clause and catch an exception if thrown. For a regular expression to be used it would have to be complex, in part because it would have to implement all the rules for determining if a year is a leap year (it's not, for example, if the year is evenly divided by 100,  but not by 400). Needless to say, a regular expression is not the right tool for the job here.

Comment: While I suggest using [DateTime::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime), I caution use of [Date#parse](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse), which is notoriously unreliable. For example, if `parse`'s argument (a string) contains the word "may" or "march" (or even a word that begins with "may" or "march", such as "marching" and "maybe"), it will dutifully turn the string into a date.

Answer (score 1):

Proper validation of `YYYY-MM-DD` aka *ISO8601* format would be:

```rb
require 'date'
input = '2019-12-11'
Date.parse(input).to_s == input
```

Regular expressions should not be used for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

[show result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FaIu.png)suppose you are validate 1900-2019

```
/^(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-1][0-9])-(0[0-9]|1[0-2])-(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$/
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it helps.